# PS - Check a log file for particular text within a certain timeframe

Tags: powershell, file, text, contains, getdate

I'm trying to get this to work within a PowerShell script, but it comes back with not defined.

```
$file = Get-Content "C:\log\clock.log"
$checktime = $(Get-Date).AddHours(-1)
$containsWord = $file | %{$_ -match "Calling ClockServer.stop()"} | $checktime
if ($containsWord -contains $true) {
    Write-Host "Calling ClockServer.stop() text has been found"
} else {
    Write-Host "Calling ClockServer.stop() text hasn't been found"
}
```

Would really appreciate the help.

Cheers

The script works if I remove the `| $checktime` part at the end of `$containsWord` variable.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it comes back with not defined"? Is that part of an error message? If so, please post the error message _in full_. What is it that you're hoping to achieve with `... | $checktime`?

Comment: Im not really too sure what you trying to do with the $checktime there, you can't pipe the line of the file, into a string like that. Are you trying to note the time at which that line in the file was found? Also when using -match, it uses regex, so you have to escape the . and ( ) characters like this:

"Calling ClockServer\.stop\(\)"

https://regex101.com/   is an awesome site, for building regex's for -match statements

Comment: Providing a few lines of the `clock.log` file would be helpful.

Comment: So, I wanted to check if the error line had appeared within the log file in the past 1 hour, otherwise it will keep alerting me that the error was present and I may have already had an alert and restarted the service myself.